# API to return the absolute path when a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon

Tags: c++, windows, path

Referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,

If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory" operation on that disk. Examples of this format are as follows:

"C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory on drive C.
"C:tempdir\tmp.txt" refers to a file in a subdirectory to the current directory on drive C.

Is there any API to return the absolute path
ie, when "C:tmp.txt" is passed, it should return C:"Current working directory"\temp.txt

GetFullPathName returns C:\temp.txt..

Comment: Given the current directory includes the drive specifier why do you not just strip it off and return current directory + "\" + inputfilename?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I would say that would be classified as bad input (or bad specification).

There is no such API. What you can do is to find out if the third character is path-separator or not. If it is, it is fully-qualified path. Otherwise, use `GetCurrentDirectory`, and make full-path out of this bad-formed path. Following command, from `C:` prompt, will display directory of `D:`

```
C:\> DIR D:*.pdf
```

As you know that drive level current-directory is not maintained and application must keep track of it. `SetCurrentDirectory` sets only the current-path for the process, without any regard to drive.

Comment: The input is valid according to the specification which is very clear on that.

Answer (score 2):

The API [`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properly merges the current directory with the given file path if it is relative, for instance `C:tmp.txt` will produce `C:\Users\<accountname>\tmp.txt` if `C:\Users\<accountname>` is the current working directory.

There probably was some confusion for 'nikithabm' because `C:\` was the current working directory when he/she tested it.